# Let $f,g:D\to\Bbb R,$ such that $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=c,$ then, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f\circ g(x)=f(c).$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

Let $f,g:D\to\Bbb R,$ where $(a,\infty)\subseteq D$ for some $a\in D$ such that $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=c,$ with a further assumption that $g(D)\subseteq D$ then, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f\circ g(x)=f(c).$

I am trying to prove this theorem for a long time now. My attempt so far:

Let $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c).$

This means, $\forall \epsilon\gt 0,$ $\exists \delta \gt 0$  such that  $\forall x\in D$ and $|x-c|\lt \delta$ we have, $|f(x)-f(c)|\lt\epsilon.$

Again, $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=c$ means that, $\forall \epsilon\gt 0,\exists b \gt a$ such that $\forall x\gt b$ we have, $|g(x)-c|\lt \epsilon.$

Now, we must try to show that $\forall \epsilon,\exists M \gt a$ such that $|f\circ g(x)-f(c)|\lt \epsilon.$

Let $\epsilon\gt 0.$

Then, for $V_{\epsilon}(f(c))$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\forall x\in V_{\delta}(c)\cap D$  then, $f(x)\in V_{\epsilon}(f(c)).$

Now, for $V_{\delta}(c),$ $\exists M\gt a$ such that, $\forall x\gt M$ we have, $g(x)\in V_{\delta }(c).$

So, for $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $M\gt a$ such that $\forall x>M$  we have, $g(x)\in V_{\delta}(c)$ and due to which, further we have, $f\circ g(x)\in V_{\epsilon}(f(c)).$

Finally, for $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $M\gt a$ such that $\forall x>M$ we have, $f\circ g(x)\in V_{\epsilon}(f(c)).$

Now, since, $\epsilon\gt 0$ is arbitrary so, $\lim_{x\to \infty}f\circ g(x)=f(c).$

---

Is this proof correct? Are there any improvements that can be made? Can I further improve the readability of this proof? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done a little easier like the following.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Take $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\tilde{\delta}$. Take $b$ such that $|g(x)-c|<\delta$ whenever $x>b$. Then for $x>b$, $|g(x)-c|<\delta$, so $|f(g(x))-f(c)|<\varepsilon$ because of the choice of $\delta$.

But to answer your question, your proof is still correct. Just a little more complicated than it needs to be.